# The usage of "univocal"

Tags: word-usage

I wrote:

> I want to say that the Iran’s stance over Israel is not **univocal**. Some could be idealists, or there could be a benefit for some others of this opposition. On the other side, there are politicians who seek a more pragmatic position toward Israel and the world.

Is it a correct usage of it? Is it used more as a single adjective or in an adjective phrase, such as "univocal voice"?

Comment: **Univocal** is a very rarely-used word.  I think that **unanimous**, used as a single adjective, would be a better choice.

Comment: Iran's stance on Israel is unequivocal. [By the way, you need help with the rest of your paragraph.] Unequivocal means no one can mistake it for something else.

Comment: **is unequivocal** is not  Ahmad's intended meaning.

Comment: **monolithic** is a word that often is used in this context.  Iran's attitude towards Israel is **not monolithic**.   mono = uni

Comment: "exhibiting or characterized by often rigidly fixed uniformity   -- *monolithic party unity*" per Merriam Webster.  " intractably indivisible and uniform" per Google.

Answer (score 2):

"Univocal" is a word made of two parts.  Both are derived from Latin.  The prefix "uni" means "one" or "singular", and "vocal" refers to "voice".  Thus the meaning of "univocal" is "of one voice", or "having one meaning".

It is not a word in common use -- so much so that my in-browser dictionary flags it as wrong.  As Canadian Yankee mentions, *unanimous* is a much more common word that means the same thing (again from the Latin, *uni*="one" and *animus*="mind", "of one mind").

If you feel you must use it, then your sentence is fine as written.  You can use *univocal* in the same way as you use *unanimous*:

> The legislature passed the bill with **univocal** approval.
>
> The union's support of the candidate was **univocal**.

One more warning:  It's likely people will think you *meant* to write *unequivocal* (*un*="not", *equi*="equal", *voc*="voice", "not having two equal meanings") because, again, that is a much more common word.  While the meaning is similar, it's used to indicate *certainty* rather than *agreement*.

> The union's support of the candidate was **unequivocal**. (without debate)

Answer (score 1):

**Univocal** is an apt word for your context, but it is a word used rarely by those without university education. So, depending on your target audience, it may be a very good word, or you may wish to simplify:

> Iran does not speak with one voice. There are factions within the
>   government...